# use Find command to copy and change names

Tags: linux, find, console

Hello I have a bunch of folders with several images (`jpg` and `png`) at the same directory level (`./ParentDirectory/contents/1680x1050.png` for example) called the same (`1680x1050.jpg` or `1680x1050.png`) on different subdirectories,

I want to know if it's possible to use the `find` command to copy this files to a different directory (e.g. `./Something/`) keeping the name but adding the parent name to the file name so at the end they are as  `./Something/ParenDirectory_1680x1050.jpg` and `ParenDirectory_1680x1050.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `cd`ing to the parent directory of `ParentDirectory`, run:

```
find ParentDirectory -type f \( -name "1680x1050.png" -o -name "1680x1050.jpg" \) \
  -exec sh -c 'cp "$1" "Something/${1%%/*}_${1##*/}"' sh {} \;
```

In the `-exec` part where a new shell process is executed for each `png` or `jpg` found, the path to the image `{}` is passed as argument `$1` to the shell script.

In the `cp` command the target filename is put together and `${1%%/*}` is used to get the parent directory name removing the longest suffix pattern (everything after the first `/`)
and `${1##*/}` is used to get the filename part removing the longest prefix pattern (all characters until the last `/`).

To achieve the same result executing only one shell process for all images found, you could use

```
find ParentDirectory -type f \( -name "1680x1050.png" -o -name "1680x1050.jpg" \) \
  -exec sh -c 'for i; do cp "$i" "Something/${i%%/*}_${i##*/}"; done' sh {} +
```

and loop through all filename arguments in the script with a `for`-loop.